# run a submit form once selected

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I am having a small issue, I am trying to run a `$("form#picform").submit`

after this function

```
$('select[name="phototype"]').live('change',function(){

if (this.value) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

I need that to run this function

```
$("form#pendingpic").submit(function(){
    alert($('#picid').val());
    return false;
});
```

here is my full js file.

```
    var session = null;
var sessionparts = null;





$(document).ready(function(){


    window.scrollTo(0, 1);


    $('select[name="phototype"]').live('change',function(){
    var $el = $(this);

    if ($el.val()) {
        $el.closest('form').submit();
    }   

      $("form#pendingpic").trigger('submit');
    });

    if ($.cookies.get('_Squirtnow_AdminSession') != null) {
           session = $.cookies.get('_Squirtnow_AdminSession');
           successlogin();
        }


    $('ul#mainmenu a li').live('click', function(event){
            //alert(this.id);

            $("li#"+lastpageid).removeClass();
            fetchpage(this.id);


            var text = '';
            $('a li#'+this.id+'').contents().each(function(){
            if(this.nodeType === 3){
             text += this.wholeText;
            }
            });

            $("#largemenutop").html(text);

            $("li#"+this.id).addClass("active");
            lastpageid = this.id;
    });



    });

//form code
$(function() {   

    $("form#pendingpic").submit(function(){
        //alert($('#picid').val());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "goog.php",
            data: "process=1&username="+ username +"&password="+ password,
            success: function(data){
            if((data) == 1)
            {
                $('#notify').fadeOut(10);
                session = $.cookies.get('_Squirtnow_AdminSession');
                successlogin();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#notify').show();
                $('#notifytext').html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                $('#notify').fadeOut(1000);
                }, 4000);
                }
            }

        });

        return false;
    });

    $("form#login").submit(function() {

        var username    = $('#username').attr('value');
        var password    = SHA1($('#password').attr('value'));


        $('#notify').show();
                $('#notifytext').html("Please wait...<br/>We are processing your login form.");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sys/classes/userlogin.php",
            data: "process=1&username="+ username +"&password="+ password,
            success: function(data){
            if((data) == 1)
            {
                $('#notify').fadeOut(10);
                session = $.cookies.get('_Squirtnow_AdminSession');
                successlogin();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#notify').show();
                $('#notifytext').html(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                $('#notify').fadeOut(1000);
                }, 4000);
                }
            }

        });
    return false;





    });

    //end of code
});


function successlogin(){
    sessionparts = session.split('|');
    changelayout();
    fetchmenus();
//  basicinfomenu();
//  checkuserprofile();
    fetchpage("home");
}



function fetchmenus(){

    $("<a href='#/page/home'><li id='home'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='home'/><br/>Home</li></a>").appendTo("ul#left");
    $("<a href='#/page/pendingusers'><li id='pendingusers'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='pendingusers'/><br/>Pending Users</li></a>").appendTo("ul#left");
    $("<a href='#/page/pendingpictures'><li id='pendingpictures'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='pendingpictures'/><br/>Pending Pictures</li></a>").appendTo("ul#left");

    $("<a href='#/page/sendmail'><li id='sendmail'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='sendmail'/><br/>Send Mail</li></a>").appendTo("ul#right");
    $("<a href='#/page/users'><li id='users'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='users'/><br/>Users</li></a>").appendTo("ul#right");
    $("<a href='#/page/stats'><li id='stats'><img src='theme/images/space.png' id='menu' class='stats'/><br/>Stats</li></a>").appendTo("ul#right");


}



function changelayout(){
    $("#successloginfull").html("<ul id='left'></ul>   <ul id='right'></ul>   <div id='mainarea'><div id='mainmenuheader'></div><div id='htmlarea'></div></div>");  

$("#onehundredpercent").hide();
$("#successloginfull").show();
}





function fetchpage(e){

        if(e == "home")
        {
            $("<div id='pendpicarea' class='threeten'></div><div id='trackingarea' class='threeten'></div><div id='sysmessagearea' class='threeten'></div>").appendTo("#htmlarea");

            homependingpics();
            hometrackusers();

        }

}


function homependingpics(){
    $.getJSON('sys/classes/fetch.php?fetch=pendingpic',function(fetchpendingpics){
                            // get line status

        $.each(fetchpendingpics, function(i,item){
            $("<div id='box'><img src='../sys/classes/fetchpicture.php?pic="+item.id+":917715617567156645'><form method='post' id='pendingpic' name='pendingpic'><input name='picid' type='hidden' id='picid' value='"+item.id+"'/><select name='phototype' id='phototype'><option value='' disabled>Rate Pic</option><option value='1'>G Rated</option><option value='2'>X Rated</option></select></form></div>").appendTo("#pendpicarea");    
        })

    })  
}

function hometrackusers(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.getJSON('sys/classes/fetch.php?fetch=trackusers',function(fetchpendingpics){
                            // get line status

            $.each(fetchpendingpics, function(i,item){
                $("").appendTo("#trackingarea");
            })

        })
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: So what is your issue exactly?

Comment: Its not triggering the form it reloads the page as a $_GET method

Comment: @Russell. Just making sure, before we check any further.. is your form tage method attribute set to post?

Comment: It is now.
basiclly the form is made out of the js, I have come to figure out in the past I need to put form submits in another js, and call that js file when ever i make a form out of a js file.

Ok that sounds strange, but personally there has to be a better way?

I have posted the full js file the parts of interest would the the homependingpics function where the form is made, and the top part of the JS

Comment: i've noticed that you have multiple form submit function thee. just checking when you do the submit does it goes into the proper function, as should appear via the alert you put there.

Comment: @melaos no the trigger does not even go to the form submit function

Comment: could the reason be that there is more then one form with the same id?

Comment: Ok seems I will have to go with my old version of, include a

var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'db.js/dbjs.js';
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 

When I do this it works.

The form function is now in that file and all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name="phototype"]').live('change',function(){
  var $el = $(this);

  if ($el.val()) {
    $el.closest('form').submit();
  }

  $("form#pendingpic").trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: mmm, that seems to refreash the page instead of sending it to the form submit

Comment: What does Firebug console say?

Comment: in the function `$("form#pendingpic").submit(...)` can you include an `alert('test');` or a `console.log('test');` and see if that gets run?